# How to detect dataChanged() and resourcesChanged() from QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-signals, qqmllistproperty

The codes below:

```
Item{
    onDataChanged: console.log("Data changed")
}

Item{
    onResourcesChanged: console.log("Resources changed")
}
```

throw `Cannot assign to non-existent property "onDataChanged"` and `Cannot assign to non-existent property "onResourcesChanged"` respectively.

This is not the case with the `childrenChanged()` signal. The reason for this is that in `qtdeclarative/src/quick/items/qquickitem.h`, `children` property is declared with:

```
Q_PRIVATE_PROPERTY(QQuickItem::d_func(), QQmlListProperty<QQuickItem> children READ children NOTIFY childrenChanged DESIGNABLE false)
```

but this is not the case for `data` or `resources`. They are declared with:

```
Q_PRIVATE_PROPERTY(QQuickItem::d_func(), QQmlListProperty<QObject> data READ data DESIGNABLE false)
Q_PRIVATE_PROPERTY(QQuickItem::d_func(), QQmlListProperty<QObject> resources READ resources DESIGNABLE false)
```

with no `changed()` signal. Why is this design choice to particularly hide the change on non-visible children made? Moreover, how can the change on `data` be detected from QML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need this ?

One possible workaround is to listen for [child events](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchildevent.html). I wrote a quick attached type PoC :

#### ChildListener.h :

```cpp
#ifndef CHILDLISTENER_H
#define CHILDLISTENER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtQml>

class ChildListener : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ChildListener(QObject *object) : QObject(object) {
        if (object)
            object->installEventFilter(this);
    }

    static ChildListener *qmlAttachedProperties(QObject *object) {
        return new ChildListener(object);
    }

signals:
    void childAdded(QObject* child);
    void childRemoved(QObject* child);

protected:
      bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) override {
          Q_UNUSED(obj)
          if (QChildEvent *childEvent = dynamic_cast<QChildEvent*>(event)) {
              if (childEvent->added())
                  emit childAdded(childEvent->child());
              if (childEvent->removed())
                  emit childRemoved(childEvent->child());
          }
          return false;
      }
};

QML_DECLARE_TYPEINFO(ChildListener, QML_HAS_ATTACHED_PROPERTIES)

#endif // CHILDLISTENER_H
```

Register it with `qmlRegisterUncreatableType<ChildListener>("fr.grecko.ChildListener", 1, 0, "ChildListener", "ChildListener can only be accessed as an attached type.");` and you can now use it like so :

```
import fr.grecko.ChildListener 1.0
/* ... */
Timer {
    id: foo
    objectName: "My name is foo"
}
Item {
    ChildListener.onChildAdded: print("child added : ", child)
    data: [foo];
}
```

This outputs : `qml: child added :  QQmlTimer(0x7ffe22f538e0, "My name is foo")` in the console

Comment: Why do I need it? I was looking for a way to autodetect certain types of children (custom types that I created that eventually extend `Item`) and `onChildrenChanged()` works for that. Then, for curiosity, I started thinking about non-visible children, like the `Timer` in your example.